# Is there a vocal technique used here? If so, what is it called?

Tags: voice, terminology

(0:53)
I'm looking at this song "Just Hold Me" by Maria Mena which I found to be a very good song in terms of the vocals.
Though I'm curious, is there actually a specific vocal technique for this part of the chorus? It's ascending and I feel like there is a name for this.

Comment: Please add a description of the video and the technique so that your question will remain useful even if the video link goes dead.

Comment: One syllable ("Why") being sung over multiple notes is *melisma*, we have lots of questions on it. I can't transcribe the ascending notes that "Why" is set to right now, but I doubt there's a special name.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a register change between the lower and higher notes, which might be the technique of interest.

Answer (score 1):

As one commenter said, a group of notes sung to one syllable of text is called a melisma, but one wouldn't consider that a "vocal technique". It's a composition choice followed by the singer. Further, she is singing more-or-less a melodic scale (up, then down-and-up), but again, one wouldn't consider that a vocal technique either. She is just singing the written score.

Vocal technique would include switching from full-voice to head-voice (which one could arguably say she did at the crescendo of the run). Or using vibrato (which she did for a split second at the crescendo). Or using special breathing techniques to handle long phrases (which she isn't for the single word). Otherwise, I'd say she's not using any distinguishable "vocal technique" during that run.